# Symfony 4 manually lazy load service in custom factory

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, factory, symfony4

I would like to know is there any way(within reason) to manually lazy load service in your custom factory, after DIC is build. I didn't find anything in docs or on SO so far. Here's explanation of what I want to achieve:

```
class ExampleFactory 
{
    .
    .
    .

    public function create() 
    {
        return new Example(new LazyLoadedDependency());
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

So I got factory for Example class and that example class takes dependency which I would like to be lazy loaded.

If I set LazyLoadedDependency() to lazy: true in my services.yml of course it will not work because I'm using that factory after DIC is built. Therefore when I try to new it up it will always be fully initialised. I would like to force Symfony to lazy load that. I've seen there's couple of files in Symfony native code but seems like it's more complicated thing.

Does anyone know how to do this? Every tip how I can do this would be great help.

Comment: Why do you need custom factories if you have DI? Are you looking for `shared: false` in your service definition?

Comment: Wrote my own param converter and it is newing up special Request class for me(that's where I use factory, it is only created when I need it). I use it to move data around, it also has special abilities. By this I mean ability to serialize data to array or other format(so I just do $request->toArray()). In order to do this I need to pass new serializer instance into it when I create my Request class. I just want to make it as light as possible. I hope I didn't make it to blurry. If u got more questions just ask.

Comment: Could you make your factory a service on its own, pass the container and fetch a lazy loaded service on creating a new instance?

Comment: I will try that. In the mean time I got a question. Isn't that defeating te purpose of the whole thing? I mean, I though that's kinda heavy solution and not a good practice?

Comment: So I've tried that and even when it's set to lazy(also needs to be set as public because by default in Symfony 4 services are private) I get full initialized object.